# Como fazer uma div com 100% de altura? (passando o viewport)

Tags: html, css

Quero colocar uma imagem de background nesta div, já tentei com height:100% mas a altura da div está se limitando a altura do viewport, sendo que quando se rola para baixo, a div termina, e também a imagem de fundo.

Comment: Tentou colocar um `position: fixed`?

Comment: Usei isso e funcionou aqui.

Comment: @Herison caso queira saber mais sobre como essa propriedade funciona aconselho ler o post no link abaixo, muito interessante, explica oque cada um dos atributos de `position` faz e seus impactos no layout. [Propriedade position do css](http://tableless.com.br/propriedade-position-do-css/)

Comment: Porque não colocar o background no body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplesmente adicione a propriedade `position: fixed` na sua `div`.